# Is there any way I can use a SliverGrid outside a ScrollView?

Tags: dart, flutter, flutter-sliver

I was trying to use a GridView without a scrolling behavior, and I achieved it by setting the "primary" attribute to false. By doing so I noticed that when one scrollable widget are nested to another, the card shadow gets this weird effect.

[Note the difference between the shadow of the two cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxNd6.png)

So I tried to get it working by using a SliverGrid, but I found out that I need to wrap it in a CustomScrollView or related, and by doing so I would create the shadow effect again. Is there any way I can use SliverGrid that allows me not to have a scrolling behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a much easier solution.
Use [`Wrap`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Wrap-class.html) instead of `GridView`

Wrap is similar to Column and Row. But it's two dimensional. 
It also has the cool ability to control spacing between items.

Comment: Did not know that yet. It would be nicer if I could set the crossAxisCount like I can do in GridView, making all the children share all the available space.

Comment: You can do that, by wraping your `Wrap` into a `LayoutBuilder`. `LayoutBuilder` gives you the parent size. You can then use the width/height divided by your desired crossAxisCount to size your children.